# How to execute GROUP BY SUM()

Tags: sql, group-by

```
SELECT x,y,SUM(f)-SUM(g) 
FROM a,b 
WHERE a.x = b.x 
GROUP BY SUM(f)-SUM(g)
HAVING SUM(f)-SUM(g)>1
```

When trying with GROUP BY x, it works but how can I GROUP BY SUM(f)-SUM(g) ??

Comment: Are you trying to group (aggregate) your x & y values by the sum value, or just order by the sum value?

Comment: I wanted to order by sum value, 
just inserted ORDER BY command at the right place and it worked thx

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to group by aggregate columns. What you need is

```
SELECT x,y,SUM(f)-SUM(g)  
FROM a,b  
WHERE a.x = b.x  
GROUP BY x,y 
HAVING SUM(f)-SUM(g)>1
```